# Мелкая опечатка на странице "Stack Overflow на русском отключен для техн. обслуживания"

Tags: дефект, локализация

> Обычно, техническое обслуживание дли**ться** менее часа. Если что–то пойдет не так, @StackStatus обязательно сообщит об этом в Твиттере или опубликует детали в специальном блоге.

[image: Скриншот]

Должно быть "дли**тся**", без мягкого знака.

Comment: Ух, 2 года назад! Однако...))